# If I change the attributes on a previously serialized property, will it be deserialized correctly?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, serialization, attributes, c#-8.0

In Unity (2020.3.8f1), let's say I have three `UnityEngine.PropertyAttribute`-derived attributes, e.g.:

```
public class EmptyExampleAttribute : PropertyAttribute {
}

public class IntExampleAttribute : PropertyAttribute {
    private int value;
    public IntExampleAttribute (int v) { value = v; }
}

// Does this even accomplish anything? It *does* compile with no warnings...
[Serializable]
public class StrangeAttribute : PropertyAttribute {
    [SerializeField] private int value;
    public StrangeAttribute (int v) { value = v; }
}
```

Now, if I have some serialized properties in a `MonoBehaviour` that I #conditionally apply these attributes to:

```
public class SomeBehaviour : MonoBehaviour {

#if SOME_CONDITION
    [EmptyExample] public bool Property1;
    [IntExample(1)] public bool Property2;
    [Strange(5)] public bool Property3;
#else
    public bool Property1;
    public bool Property2;
    public bool Property3;
#endif

}
```

Under the assumption that I'm not actually *doing* anything with those attributes in my code (in particular I'm not *intentionally* modifying serialization stuff when I see them - re: [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67620159/do-propertyattributes-affect-property-serialization-format?noredirect=1#comment119527381_67620159)), my question is:

Will the presence alone of any of these attributes affect the serialization of `SomeBehaviour` in a way that will cause format incompatibilities if `SOME_CONDITION` has a different value on deserialization than it did when the object was originally serialized by Unity?

In other words, assuming I know that my attributes aren't *explicitly* messing with serialization, can I safely change the attributes of a property without breaking previously serialized data?

Comment: well .. depends ... if your tag was e.g. [`[NonSerialized]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.nonserializedattribute) you could be pretty sure it has an impact on the (de)serialization ;) The same the other way round imaagine you have a `[SerializeField] private bool someBool;` .. removing or adding that `[SerializeField]` of course would change the serialization .. in such case you should get a warning the moment the object is deserialized by Unity

Comment: @derHugo Well........... yeah, hah. I'll edit to clarify that I didn't mean attributes that were intentionally *designed* to affect serialization.

Comment: Could you give an example what attributes we are talking about? ;) In general if as you have showed it is only an empty attribute it shouldn't have any impact at all. In Unity you usually use them for custom property drawers and decorators. So I guess it pretty much depends on the exact use case

Comment: @derHugo Well, the example code I gave with the empty attribute is accurate. But yeah it's actually an inspector-related attribute that spawned this question (I've got a custom drawer that just disables the field in the editor if a `[NoEdit]` attribute is present, where `NoEdit` itself is empty like my example). But this question isn't limited to that. However, I see it's kind of vague and poorly written now. I'm going to try to make it a better question. Give me a couple minutes. (You did just answer the empty attribute part of my question though, thanks!!)

Comment: So if I understand you correctly you want certain fields to be serialized but not editable when a certain target platform is selected, right? In this case I'm pretty confident to claim: No, it shouldn't have any impact on the serialization itself. In such case though I would probably rather implement a `[NoEditOnPlatform (...)]` and pass in a list or enum flag etc of platforms. This way you would save a bit of typing and potential pitfalls of platform dependent compilations (e.g. renaming of fields etc)

Comment: @derHugo I updated the question. Also good tip on the `[NoEditOnPlatform]` style approach; then I could do any logic that depended on the preprocessor in the attribute implementation itself and leave it out of the behaviors. My questions still stand, but for the particular case I was talking about, what you just said is definitely better, I'm going to do that instead in this code.

Comment: Oh that `StrangeAttribute` is indeed am interesting case .. and indeed strange as well :D Not sure if this will actually do something since afaik the parameters to attributes have to be compile time constant anyway so it wouldn't really make sense to serialize such a value inside the attribute itself ..